# Default save location for Outlook attachments

Tags: microsoft-outlook

If I try to save an attachment that I've opened from Microsoft Outlook, the default save folder is somewhere within temporary internet files. How can I change this default location

Answer (score 3):

If you save an attachment in, say, My Documents, that will be the save location the next time you go to save an attachment if I remember rightly.

Comment: You remembered correctly. That's what it does for me in Outlook 2003.

Comment: That would be the perfect behaviour, but its doesn't do that for me (also Outlook 2003)